# How to add a new tab into Customer's Dashboard on M2 frontend

Tags: magento2, frontend, customer-account

I need to create a new tab in M2's customer dashboard. I tried to do it the way they do in the core: put a xml file in view/frontend/layout

```
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="customer_account_navigation">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="customer-account-navigation-my-block-name">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">module/controller</argument>
                <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">My Tab Name</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

I also tried the addLink method like in M1 but did not work out also. What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**app/code/Learning/Custom/view/frontend/layout/customer_account.xml**

```
<xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="customer_account_navigation">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="customer-account-navigation-customlearning-link">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">customlearning/index</argument>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Custom Link</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Clear magento cache

Comment: </argument> is missing in first argument due to editor.

Comment: You are missing the "?" at the <xml ... ?> tag. Should be <?xml ...?> :)